# Amazon EC2: how to convert an existing PV AMI to HVM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

### Question:

How should I use the new AWS EC2 classes (r3, i2) with my existing AMI without recreating the whole system setup?

The new EC2 classes support only HVM based virtualization but I have only PVM AMI images.

Comment: Just tried this with CentOS but end up ins tep 10 with following error:
/dev/xvdf does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.

Comment: Further to what @ROMANARMY said, I reckon the answer *should* be split out into a proper answer.  Then you can accept it so the question won't show up as unanswered. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @Tobias Zander did you ever get this working with CentOS?

Comment: @dennis.hempler We didn't invest a lot more time and just created new instances

Answer (score 77):

### Answer:

1. Start an Ubuntu HVM linux, any version, new
2. Start an Ubuntu / with my existing AMI / PVM linux, and install grub packages on them: `apt-get install  grub-pc  grub-pc-bin grub-legacy-ec2 grub-gfxpayload-lists`
3. Stop PVM linux
4. Detach root (/dev/sda1) partition at PVM linux
5. Attach PVM linux root partition to running HVM linux somewhere, e.g.: /dev/sdf
6. On HVM linux: `mkdir -p /mnt/xvdf && mount /dev/xvdf /mnt/xvdf`
7. `rsync -avzXA /boot/ /mnt/xvdf/boot/`
8. `mount -o bind /dev /mnt/xvdf/dev && mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/xvdf/dev/pts && mount -o bind /proc /mnt/xvdf/proc && mount -o bind /sys /mnt/xvdf/sys`
9. `chroot /mnt/xvdf`
10. `grub-install --no-floppy --recheck --force /dev/xvdf`
11. `update-grub2`
12. exit chroot: CTRL+D
13. stop HVM Linux
14. detach /dev/sda1 original root AND detach /dev/sdf PVM root
15. attach PVM root to HVM linux as /dev/sda1
16. Start HVM linux, voilà!
17. Create a new AMI image from the running HVM linux, it will be HVM virtualized.

Comment: Worked perfectly...once I created the HVM instance on the exact same availability zone as the PVM volume.

Comment: I get a the following warning when running grub-install: `warning: Embedding is not possible.  GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using blocklists.  However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
/usr/sbin/grub-bios-setup: error: will not proceed with blocklists.`
Then, everything looks good but it doesn't boot or give me any clue, why it is not booting.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, thank you so much!  I did get the scary grub warnings that Paulo Neves reported above, but my new instance booted fine anyway.

Comment: I have an AMI Linux PVM instance and I am trying to migrate it to a new HVM AMI Linux instance.  I tried to apply your solutions but I am stuck at step 10. Could someone please elaborate on how to do this for a new AMI Linux instance instead of Ubuntu? Thanks!

Comment: I worked it out by manually transferring all files to the new instance. http://serverfault.com/a/678867/165528

Comment: Works like a charm! Maybe add step 5.5 "On HVM linux: sudo su -"
as the mount command requires the "root" user and can't be done using sudo.

Comment: @tolgamorf. You would probably have to install grub first on AWS Linux: yum install grub -y

Comment: I'm having the same issue as tolgamorf. Installing grub first on AMS Linux helped, but didn't solve the problem. Instead of getting a message that grub didn't exist, I got this message (had to omit --force command because not supported): grep: /boot/grub/device.map: No such file or directory
mv: cannot stat ‘/boot/grub/device.map’: No such file or directory
Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. This may take a long time.
Unknown partition table signature
/dev/xvdf does not have any corresponding BIOS drive.

Comment: Just upgraded my AMI thanks to this tutorial. Works perfectly at one exception: Docker. I had to completely uninstall and reinstall it to make it up and working again.

Comment: Does not work for me in step 5; I get message Error attaching volume: The instance configuration for this AWS Marketplace product is not supported. Please see http://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp?sku=8fvdn95s5ev33cprr62nq3q7t for more information about supported instance types, regions, and operating systems.

Comment: @PauloNeves - I am encountering the same issue.  Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: @curtp: It was a long time ago so I dont really rememeber, but I have the idea it was something about the drive with our without letter that I was putting wrong and when i followed exactly it worked.

Comment: Just upgraded a Ubuntu PV to a Ubuntu HVM machine as per the procedure, confirming it still works perfectly well.

Comment: I confirm this works for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Some apps need extra kernel modules that depends on architeture. For instance, if you have docker installed, it may be necessary to run this command after everything on the new HVM instance: "sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-$(uname -r)"

Comment: That's smart! Have a fresh HVM instance, mount the PV root volume, copy the HVM boot, then chroot and update grub. Simple! +1000

Comment: Cannot find pkgs in setp2 in ubuntu 10.04

Comment: Instance is unreachable when using a newer instance type (such as C5). There is no `xvd*` on these instances, there is only `nvme*` naming conventions. Replacing `xvd` with the correct `nvme` does not work. :(

Comment: I used this for a Rackspace XEN CentOS server to run it on a local VirtualBox.  One issue - I had to clear the PV /boot/ directory completely.  Not sure what it was but some cruft in there was preventing booting (could not mount disk).

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @divyenduz works but needs some cleanup and clarification for modern (circa 2019) AWS EC2. Importantly, modern instance classes translate the device name differently.

Here are my modified steps.

For clarity, nodes are:

- Original PVM node that you want to upgrade to HVM is "PVM01"
- New HVM node that you will migrate PVM01's root disk to is "HVM01"

**BEFORE PROCEEDING: Back up Original Node PVM01**

1. Install prerequisites on Node PVM01

   - install grub packages on PVM01

     ```
     apt-get install  grub-pc  grub-pc-bin grub-legacy-ec2 grub-gfxpayload-lists
     ```
2. Stop node PVM01

   - Create snapshot of /dev/sda1
   - OR create AMI of entire node
3. Create snapshot of original root volume on PVM01 and create new volume from this snapshot

   - Create snap of /dev/sda1 on PVM01
   - Create vol from this snap
   - **Label each resource accordingly**

     - Tag: Name; Value: pvm01:/dev/sda1:snapshot-for-conversion-to-hvm:2019-07-01
     - Etc
4. create-instance: New Ubuntu HVM instance "HVM01". Any instance class should work; however, device name may be different, see notes, below

   - I used Bionic Ubuntu 18.04 HVM AMI ID ami-0a313d6098716f372 and instance class C5.XLARGE
5. Attach PVM01 root partition (new volume from previous step) to new HVM01 /dev/sdf

   - **NOTE**: Older instance classes such as C3 will translate the volume name to /dev/xvdf
   - **NOTE**: Newer instance classes such as C5 will translate the volume name to /dev/nvme1

     - On newer instance classes, the **root vol** will be /dev/nvme0 -- ZERO
     - On newer instance classes, the **attached, secondary vol** will be /dev/nvme1 -- ONE
   - Make a note of the attached volume device name

   ssh PVM01
   sudo fdisk -l
6. On HVM01:

   ```
   # For xvdf, e.g. on C3.XLARGE
   DEVNAME=xvdf1
   # For nvme, e.g. on C5.XLARGE
   DEVNAME=nvme1n1
   mkdir -p /mnt/${DEVNAME} && mount /dev/${DEVNAME} /mnt/${DEVNAME}
   rsync -avzXA /boot/ /mnt/${DEVNAME}/boot/
   mount -o bind /dev /mnt/${DEVNAME}/dev && mount -o bind /dev/pts /mnt/${DEVNAME}/dev/pts && mount -o bind /proc /mnt/${DEVNAME}/proc && mount -o bind /sys /mnt/${DEVNAME}/sys
   chroot /mnt/${DEVNAME}
   grub-install --no-floppy --recheck --force /dev/${DEVNAME}
   update-grub2
   ```
7. Exit chroot with CTRL+D
8. Stop HVM01
9. Detach both volumes

   - detach /dev/nvme0 PVM01 root

     - NOTE: This would be /dev/sda1 on a C3 instance class
   - detach /dev/${DEVNAME} (DEVNAME from above script)
10. attach PVM01 root Volume to HVM01 as /dev/sda1

    - Once again, the /dev/sda1 name is in the console; this name will get translated to /dev/nvme0 or /dev/xvda1 depending on how modern the instance class is
11. Start HVM01
12. OPTIONAL: Create a new AMI image from the the now-running HVM01, it will be HVM virtualized.

Comment: This solution worked for me.  Remember to recreate the `DEVNAME` variable after the `chroot` command.

Comment: Something we ran into is that some of those older systems on PV instances might not have the enhanced networking feature enabled...we could get these to boot on HVM, but the network was unusable. Curious if there's an easy solution here?