# Amazon EC2 : Issue with converting PV AMI to HVM

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I have followed the steps to convert PV AMI to HVM listed in [Amazon EC2: how to convert an existing PV AMI to HVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330721/amazon-ec2-how-to-convert-an-existing-pv-ami-to-hvm)

I got struck in step 10. The following is the error message obtained

$ sudo grub-install --no-floppy --recheck /dev/xvdf 
sudo: unable to resolve host ip-10-154-234-204 Probing devices to guess BIOS drives. 
This may take a long time. 
Unknown partition table signature 
Unknown partition table signature 
Searching for GRUB installation directory ... found: /boot/grub 
Unknown partition table signature 
Unknown partition table signature 
The file /boot/grub/stage1 not read correctly.

Can someone help me to figure out the issue?