# change virtualization type for an instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, virtualization

I am on AWS, have created a VM with virutalization type PV. Due to some reasons I want to change the virtualization type to HVM.

Can that be done? Please explain how.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to convert PV to HVM. There are multiple steps involved and there is no guaranteed solution. Search StackOverflow for a solution. See [Amazon EC2: how to convert an existing PV AMI to HVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330721/amazon-ec2-how-to-convert-an-existing-pv-ami-to-hvm)

If you had launched a PV linux VM and installed the software from scratch, then the best way is to launch a HVM version of linux instance and then install the software again. There will not be any surprises once your instance starts running.