# How to convert existing PVM EC2 to HVM

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed all steps mentioned in the below thread.
[Amazon EC2: how to convert an existing PV AMI to HVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24330721/amazon-ec2-how-to-convert-an-existing-pv-ami-to-hvm/26276763#26276763)

My existing PVM is ubuntu 16.04 `m3.large`. I am trying to convert it to `HVM m5.large`

I tried with AMI having `ubuntu 20.04` and `ubuntu 22.04`. Once all steps were followed mentioned in the above thread, instance is not booting up and status check - `instance reachability check` is failing.

Can any one has idea about this error and also how to migrate existing m3.large to m5.large?